# Parsing string using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a input file that contains 3 copied column.

mystatement.cql

```
      ,4.CAPFMGE,2016-03-21 04:00:00+0000
      "['SHRPT_IWS', '589279_SHRPT_IWS']",4.SHRPT-IWS,2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000
      ['REFP99'],178,2015-06-29 04:00:00+0000
```

I am doing some string manipulation using awk withing my script file-

```
   awk '

     BEGIN { FS = "," }  # split fields on comma
      {
        update_fmt = "update table set cross_refs=%s where id='\''%s'\'' and eff_date='\''%s'\'';\n"
        gsub(/[\]\[\"]/,"")  # remove useless chars: [,],"
        i=1
        crefs="{"
        while (i <= (NF-2)) {  # loop from first to 3rd last field
        tmp = $(i) ? $(i) : "''"  # if no value, add empty quotes
        crefs=crefs ""tmp": "''","  # append current field value or empty to crefs
        i++
        }
        sub(/,$/, "''", crefs)  # remove trailing comma
        crefs=crefs"}"
        printf(update_fmt, crefs, $(NF-1), $NF);
       }
       ' mystatement.cql > updateStatement.cql
```

Here am writing my output to updateStatement file.
 o/p -

```
  update table set cross_refs={: } where id='4.CAPFMGE' and eff_date='2016-03-21 04:00:00+0000';
  update table set cross_refs={'SHRPT_IWS': , '589279_SHRPT_IWS': } where id='4.SHRPT-IWS' and eff_date='2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000';
  update table set cross_refs={'REFP99': } where id='178' and eff_date='2015-06-29 04:00:00+0000';
```

expected o/p-

```
   update table set cross_refs=null where id='4.CAPFMGE' and eff_date='2016-03-21 04:00:00+0000';
   update table set cross_refs={'SHRPT_IWS':'', '589279_SHRPT_IWS':''} where id='4.SHRPT-IWS' and eff_date='2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000';
   update table set cross_refs={'REFP99':''} where id='178' and eff_date='2015-06-29 04:00:00+0000';
```

Answer (score 0):

This gnu awk command should work with `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]*' 'NF == 3 {
   if ($1 == "")
      $1="null"
   sub(/"?\[/, "{", $1)
   gsub(/,/, ":\047\047,", $1)
   sub(/\]"?/, ":\047\047}", $1)
   printf "update table set cross_refs=%s where id=\047%s\047 and eff_date=\047%s\047\n",
      $1, $2, $3
}' file
```

**Output:**

```
update table set cross_refs=null where id='4.CAPFMGE' and eff_date='2016-03-21 04:00:00+0000'
update table set cross_refs={'SHRPT_IWS':'', '589279_SHRPT_IWS':''} where id='4.SHRPT-IWS' and eff_date='2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000'
update table set cross_refs={'REFP99':''} where id='178' and eff_date='2015-06-29 04:00:00+0000'
```

Comment: Sir, i know this will work for the latest version. but mine is      GNU Awk 3.1.7.. any other alternative?

Comment: You can upgrade your awk it to 4+ version. There is no other shell utility that can parse CSV data, you will need to use PHP, Perl, Python etc

Answer (score 0):

With little bit of effort i am able to get the desired output. Thanks @anubhava Sir.. i got few points from your post and modified my script with old awk version-

```
 awk '

   BEGIN { FS = "," }  # split fields on comma
   {
update_fmt = "update table set cross_refs=%s where id='\''%s'\'' and eff_date='\''%s'\'';\n"
   gsub(/[\]\[\"]/,"")  # remove useless chars: [,],"
   i=1
   crefs="{"
   while (i <= (NF-2)) {  # loop from first to 3rd last field
    tmp = $(i) ? $(i) :"\047\047"  # if no value, add empty quotes
    crefs=crefs ""tmp": '\'''\'',"  # append current field value or empty to crefs
    i++
 }
  sub(/,$/, "''", crefs)  # remove trailing comma
   crefs=crefs"}"
    printf(update_fmt, crefs, $(NF-1), $NF);
  }
   ' updatestmt.cql > updateStatement.cql
   sed -i "s/{'': ''}/null/" updateCrossStatement.cql
```

Output:

```
     update table set cross_refs=null where id='4.CAPFMGE' and eff_date='2016-03-21 04:00:00+0000'
     update table set cross_refs={'SHRPT_IWS':'', '589279_SHRPT_IWS':''} where id='4.SHRPT-IWS' and eff_date='2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000'
     update table set cross_refs={'REFP99':''} where id='178' and eff_date='2015-06-29 04:00:00+0000'
```